# Erro 500 em requisição ajax com asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver.
Fiz uma requisição ajax simples no meu código para preencher os campos automaticamente caso o cpf digitado já esteja cadastrado no banco de Dados.

Pois bem, no dia que fiz deu tudo certo e estava funcionando mil maravilhas, porém agora do nada, ele esta dando Erro 500 e diz q não encontra minha Action sendo que ele entra na action, vai no banco, pega o resultado, mas quando retorna não vai pra View.

Alguém por favor pode me ajudar?!

```
public class ParticipanteController : Controller
{
    mconfEntities db = new mconfEntities();
    // GET: Participante
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult BuscaDados(string cpf)
    {
        string pesquisaCpf = cpf.Replace(".", "");

        var dados = db.Participante.FirstOrDefault(p => p.cpf == pesquisaCpf);

        return Json(dados);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var evento = db.Evento;

        ViewBag.conferencia = new SelectList(evento, "eventoUID", "descricao");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Participante model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Participante p = new Participante()
                {
                    cpf = model.cpf,
                    nome = model.nome,
                    email = model.email,
                    telefone = model.telefone,
                    municipio = model.municipio,
                    unidadeSaude = model.unidadeSaude,
                    equipeSaude = model.equipeSaude,
                    categoriaProfissional = model.categoriaProfissional
                };

                db.Participante.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }
            catch (EntityException ex)
            {
                TempData["erro"] = "Erro ao cadastrar participante - " + ex.Message;
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["erro"] = "Participante Inválido";
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }
}


<script>
$(document).ready(
```

function () {
      $('#cpf').focusout(function () {
          debugger;
          var cpfData = $('#cpf').val().replace('.','').replace('-','');

```
      $.ajax
      ({
          url: '/Participante/BuscaDados/',
          type: "POST",
          data: { cpf: cpfData },
          success: function (data) {
              $('#nome').val(data.nome);
              $('#email').val(data.email);
              $('#telefone').val(data.telefone);
              $('#municipio').val(data.município);
              $('#unidadeSaude').val(data.unidadeSaude);
              $('#equipeSaude').val(data.equipeSaude);
              $('#categoriaProfissional').val(data.categoriaProfissional);
          }
      });
  });
```

});

O erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que postar fotos do código? Poste o código. Vou lhe dar uma dica de como formular um bom exemplo, segue o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Valeu a dica, sou novo aqui. Uma pergunta: Devo excluir essa postagem e refaze-la ou altero ela?

Comment: Não precisa excluir, basta editar. Observe que abaixo da pergunta tem 4 links: compartilhar, editar, fechar e sinalizar. Utilize o "Editar".

Comment: Beleza, já já termino a alteração

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, depois de alguns dias sem dormir e usando o Fiddler que o Fernando Medeiros indicou, descobri que era um problema de referencia Circular nas classes criadas pelo entity framework.

Solucionei colocando um `.Select(t => new {t.nome, t.email, ...})` antes do .Where() e desta forma ele conseguiu identificar qual tabela eu estava querendo pegar os dados.

O mais estranho no meu caso é que no dia que fiz o Código a parada funcionava e de repente parou de funcionar...

Muito Obrigado a Todos que ajudaram...

Solução:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult BuscaDados(string cpf)
    {      
        var dados = db.Participante.Select(t => new {t.cpf, t.nome, t.email, t.telefone, t.municipio, t.unidadeSaude, t.equipeSaude, t.categoriaProfissional } ).Where(p => p.cpf == cpf);

        return Json(dados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Passei por algo parecido esse dias,

Utilize o programa fiddler para verificar quais requisições e quais repostas você está enviando.

Em relação ao erro pode estar ligado ao tipo de retorno, experimente o retorno da seguinte forma:

```
return Json(dados, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

ou

```
//retorna uma string json
return JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(dados);
```

Agora utilize o Fiddler para verificar se a reposta está sendo enviada contendo o JSON

Comment: Eu baixei o Fiddler, o que exatamente tenho que verificar? Ele deu erro aqui mas não sei nem oq mandar...

Comment: Abra o fiddler e execute o seu site, faça a action que está dando problema ser executada, assim que o fizer vá no fiddler e procure a resposta que contém o JSON, clique sobre ele e no menu ao lado navegue sobre os campos para analisar o que está sendo enviado

Comment: Fiz isso, como posso te mandar a imagem? na parte JSON
ele ta escrito: JSON=cpf

Fiz tbm as alterações que falou, não funcionaram continua o mesmo erro...

Comment: Atualize a sua pergunta com a imagem do conteudo JSON da reposta pelo fiddler

Comment: Adicionar JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet resolve o problema. lembre-se também de definir o datatype: dataType: "json" para informar que sua requisição ira retornar um JSON.

Comment: @IvanTeles Adicionei o Behavior e o dataType e continuou o mesmo problema. alguem com Skype?

Comment: Só poderei entrar no skype mais de noite, se até lá voce nao tiver resolvido eu comento aqui

Comment: Beleza, vou tentando achar uma solução.

Comment: Adicionou tambem o  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet?

Comment: Como voce pesquisa usando o FirstorDefault() ele pode retornar null, voce verificou se não é o caso? Qual a estrutura da classe Participante?

Comment: Ivan Teles Adicionei sim
@FernandoMedeiros Ele esta retornando dados sim
da pra ver durante o debug no Visual Studio